# Agregar un Button dinamicamente a un flowlayoutpanel en una celda especifica en C#. (windows forms)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Tengo un `flowlayoupanel` en el que se van a agregando botones de forma dinámica. Esto se hace con el simple codigo que ya todos conocemos:

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(boton);
```

Sin embargo acomo al metodo *Add* no se le puede especificar una celda como al `tabletlayoutpanel`, como puedo decirle por código que me agregue en tal parte del `flowlayoutpanael` un botón? sin que lo agregue hacia arriba o hacia abajo como lo estipula su atributo `flowdirection` ?

Comment: no se puede.. esa es toda la idea del flow, que se vayan poniendo las cosas automaticamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este control no existe el concepto de "tal parte" que mencionas, le puedes definir una direccion usando

```
flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
```

para indicar los controles que agregas como se acomodan

[Working With Windows Forms FlowLayoutPanel](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/flowlayoutpanel-in-C-Sharp/)

---

Lo mas cercano que se me ocurre podria ser usando el `SetChildIndex()`

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(control, index);
```

pero no es algo exclusivo de `FlowLayoutPanel` sino que aplica sobre la coleccion de controles

[Control.ControlCollection.SetChildIndex(Control, Int32) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex?view=netframework-4.5)